# Use Respnse.WriteFile instead of user control

Tags: asp.net

I have a large html file that I want to split apart. I have managed to split it apart and place each part in a htm file. As a result my structure now looks like:

[image]

note all the files in the folder are just specific to the Default.aspx page. I like to have my code spitted into several parts; I find it easier to program that way.

Anyways why when I do:

```
    <%   
        Response.WriteFile("_Menu.htm");        
    %>
```

that creates a different output that if I where to go to _Menu.htm copying the entire content and pasting it in there? I know I can create a user control for each file. but if I do so I will have to create a page directive at the root of the page for each file and plus I just need to place static content I don't need to call an aspx page. Why does Response.WriteFile include stuff that I don't have in the file. For example it places '"' marks whenever I have a paragraph.

### EDIT

I use user controls when I plan to reuse html. In this case I am just spliting apart a page into several ones. I will like to have the content of each chunk in a separate file.

### EDIT 2

Doing:

```
    <%   

        //Response.WriteFile("_Menu.htm");

        Response.Write(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"A:\Users\Antonio\Dropbox\VisualStudio Projects\Websites\Boat\Boat\MasterPages\User\_Menu.htm"));        
    %>
```

works great. why is Response.WriteFile including " (paragraph) " at the the beginning!?

Comment: As a suggestion which may help you somewhat, I recommend that rather than making all those related html files, you should turn those into web user controls.  They would be reusable and there wouldn't be the need to output your files.

Comment: Yeah I come from a php background and I am using a lot of ajax. But yeah you are right trying to use asp as php has given me a hard time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create your Response.Write  method:

Create the following extension method globaly so all your pages can access it:

```
using System.Web.UI;

public static class StaticExtensionMethods
{
    public static void Include(this System.Web.UI.Page Page, string path)
    {
        Page.Response.Write(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Page.Server.MapPath(path))); 
    }



}
```

then do:

```
    <%   
        this.Include("_Menu.htm");
    %>
```